# Get last Twitter mention from API with Tweepy avoiding rate limit

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy, rate-limiting

I used to have some good working python that did auto-replies on the Tweepy stream listener, but due to changes in the Twitter API in August it no longer works.

I am re-building it by getting my most recent mention every 10 seconds (ideally it'd be less as I want to do near-instant replies), and checking if it was in the last ten seconds... if it was then the script assumes it's a new tweet and replies.

```
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import API
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''
account_screen_name = ''
account_user_id = '897579556009332736'

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
twitterApi = API(auth)

mentions = twitterApi.mentions_timeline(count=1)
now = datetime.now()

for mention in mentions:
    if now < (mention.created_at + timedelta(hours=1) + timedelta(seconds=10)):
        print "there's a mention in the last 10 seconds"
        # do magic reply stuff here!
    else:
        print "do nothing, no recent tweets/the last mention was more than 10 seconds ago so it isn't new"
```

This could work on a loop every 12 seconds; but any less and it hits the rate limit (i.e. this method above at 10 secs will hit the rate limit eventually)... so, is there a better way of just retrieving the most recent mention in order to do a reply based on the mention? I feel like I am probably doing it in a very inefficient way (e.g. this method actually gets the last 20 mentions!!) and the API probably has a better method that I could do more often without hitting rate limits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer**

Using tweepy: no

Using other methods: yes , but not for free

**Explanation**

First thing to understand is that twitter does allow for real-time streaming of tweets through their API.  The next thing is that it is possible to use their API to track tweets containing some `@TrackedUsername` to keep track of mentions live.  However, while the first feature is free to use through a number of libraries and wrapper APIs, the second feature is not.  It is one of their features locked behind a monthly subscription to either their premium or enterprise api.

What I do know is that people do not use tweepy as distributed to utilize these services.  Maybe someone out there has modified it for personal use compatible with such features, but if so I haven't found it.  What people use instead is the [Python Twitter API](https://python-twitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

**Speculation**

As I have never used their premium services myself it would be worth reading into what I'm about to say next, but from what I understand authentication protocol for their pay-to-use services is slightly different which is what causes problems with tweepy.

**Back to Facts**

Essentially what this means is that searching for `@TrackedUsername` will return nothing at all, and searching for `TrackedUsername` will not return tweets containing `@TrackedUsername` or `#TrackedUsername` (unless it also contains just `TrackedUsername` but then you're tracking text instead of mentions).  Basically because twitter wanted to get paid for this service.

If you do choose to pay for this service then the python implementation most commonly used is [Python Twitter API](https://python-twitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as mentioned above.  These features will allow you to track tweets that contain mentions in real-time with a higher rate limit and support for searching farther back into past tweets.

Comment: So basically Twitter is tightening up their free API services :(

Comment: @the_t_test_1 essentially yeah.  still a lot of services charge for access to any level of API.  I use roll20 for tabletop nerd gaming with distant friends but can't use any of their dev tools unless I subscribe for a monthly "premium" membership.  Been considering it lately.

Comment: does this mean there's no longer any way to stream tweets for geolocation etc? that's really sad...  e.g. as used for https://onemilliontweetmap.com/?center=51.52555160439856,-0.1318766650000125&zoom=15&search=&timeStep=0&timeSelector=0&hashtag1=&hashtag2=&hashtagBattle=0&timeRange=0&timeRange=25&heatmap=0&sun=0&cluster=1 ?

Comment: @the_t_test_1 As I understand it you can still use twitter streaming services.  But it's geared more towards personal usage.  I'm not entirely sure of all the features available but the documentation is up on twitter's dev site and last I checked there were definitely still some streaming capabilities.  I'm pretty sure the apps you linked suffered because they were trying to stream in WAY more than any one (average) person would ever use.  They were streaming for ALL the users of their apps.  Depending on what's being pulled using those streams, that could be a lot of strain on twitter servers

Comment: could be very wrong about why they shut it down, but I know a lot of personal use stuff is still either free or very affordable for use by one person.

Comment: thanks for the info... however all my app did was listen for mentions of the account's username (in order to respond immediately)... it wasn't heavy use or anything that would constitute spam/overload as far as I know. It was used on just one account for automated replies to anyone who tweeted at the account.